# Would it be possible to have the question closer to the answer field?

Tags: feature-request, answers, editing

I find that when answering a question on Code Review, I'm constantly scrolling to the top of the page, copying some code, scrolling to the bottom, pasting it, then editing it. I do this over and over. It's worse when there's already an answer or two, as there's a lot more scrolling.

Would it be possible to have the question be side-by-side with the answer editing UI? Or, maybe just the code snippets from the question?

I realize this is probably not something simple that can be done in an afternoon, but I'm just curious if others would find it useful and if it's something that could be considered in the future?

Comment: I know the Problem and usually mitigate it by adding a second screen with the same question opened again. It's still unwieldy though...

Comment: Related Stack Exchange feature request: [Can we hide the other answers while we are answering?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190136/148099)

Comment: You might also be interested in: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/78695/31562

Comment: @SimonForsberg - Wow! Pretty cool! I haven't used user scripts before, but that looks really awesome.

Comment: I asked something very similar... 2 years ago http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1755/11919